# trigamma and digamma functions for bigfloat variable in python

Tags: python, derivative, gamma-function, bigfloat

I need to compute the `scipy.special` trigamma and digamma functions of a variable with type *bigfloat* in python but I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'psi' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'
```

I need to keep my variables as bigfloat for precision purposes.
Does any body know how I can compute digamma and trigamma functions for such variables?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple precision implementations of digamma are available in [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2), [mpmath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpmath/0.19), and [Python-FLINT](http://fredrikj.net/python-flint/index.html). I am not aware of any implementations of trigamma.

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

Comment: trigamma is a special case of polygamma